# Is "in" necessary in the following?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I arrived at a motel—the same one Mary and I had spent the night (in). [They had spent the night in that motel before.]

Is *in* necessary here? Why or why not?

Comment: In this sentence, "*Mary and I had spent the night in that motel before*", you agree we need "in", right? Why do you think it's different in a relative clause? The noun "motel" still needs a preposition to connect it with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: This *in* is sometimes omitted in informal speech, but I would not recommend doing so; it suggests that the speaker has lost track of the structure of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the 'in' somewhere, or 'at', ot another specifier such as 'where'.

I arrived at a motel—the same one Mary and I had spent the night **in** or **at**.

I arrived at a motel—the same one **in which** or **at which** Mary and I had spent the night.

I arrived at a motel—the same one **where** Mary and I had spent the night.

Answer (score -1):

All of the following sentences are consistent with how most Americans used the English language between the years 1990 and 2022:

> - I arrived at a motel — the same one Mary and I had spent the previous night at
> - I arrived at a motel — the same motel Mary and I had spent the previous night in
> - I arrived at a motel — the same motel where Mary and I had spent the previous night

There is more than one correct way to word things.

You asked if it is necessary to use the word "**in**"

It is never necessary to use the word "***in***". In fact, it is never necessary to use any word in the English language, French language, or any other language. It is the choice of each person on planet earth to use words however they like. However, if your goal is to communicate that you "ate an ice-cream sand-which" and you write "***I badete a xorri***" you will fail to accomplish your goal. If you want to communicate that you ate an ice-cream sand-which then it helps to say that you "ate an ice-cream sand-which". Thus, it is selfish desire which drives some people to use words the way other people use them. I am not bound by your laws, but I am bound by my selfish desire to be understood. As such, I am willing to use your laws of language in order to accomplish my goal of conveying my thoughts.